# Extracting a value from an single value vector

Tags: openscad

In openscad I need to extract a value from an array without it being it's own array. For example I have an array of values

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

When I assign a[0] to a variable the variable echos [0] showing that the variable is a single celled array. 
For example:

```
b = a[0];
```

b = [0]; instead of just 0. How can I make b = 0?

Comment: This works exactly as you want:
a = [0,1,2,3,4];
b = a[0];
echo(b);
-> ECHO: 0

Comment: Thanks, you helped me realize what my actual problem was. I was getting the equivalent of [0] when I echod, so my problem was somewhere else.